Former Software Developer thinking of going back into software development
So I worked 4 years as a software developer.

2 years at a small startup that did consulting (I mainly worked on iOS apps there)
2 years at a big insurance company doing java spring

I had a mental crisis (March of 2023) and ended up resigning my job at the big insurance company. I thought I would never go back into software again. My plan was to go into the trades or something of the sort.
I had 2 construction jobs and got fired from both of them so I got a job as a pizza delivery driver. I have come around and now I am actually thinking of going back in to software.
I have considered the fact that nobody wanted me as a construction worker but they did not want me to leave as a software developer. Maybe that means that is what I should do.
In my free time, I have picked up Ruby on Rails and even built out a website (MCode.social). So I have some options:

Start a software business on my own
Find a job as a software developer
Find a job doing something better - could get training for welding or CDL driving

What do you guys think?

If you can find a job as a software developer, this seems the best route.  You'll have to decide carefully how to discuss the gap on the resume' while maintaining honesty.  Best wishes!

@JosephDoggie ok thank you. Do you think I should put my jobs doing construction on my resume? Or do you think I should leave them off? If I put them on, it helps show that I wasn't doing anything, but I also would have to explain that I got fired from them. But if I leave them off, then they will wonder why I didn't work for awhile. Also, do you think I should put my experience delivering pizzas on there?

@JoeStrazzere I think I have decided to go back in to software now. How do you think I should explain these things? Should I just say that I had a mental crisis and leave it up to the employer to decide hiring me? Or no?

@Slaknation I would generalize any mention to "health" (use that word only) and don't use the word crisis, e.g. "I had a health issue, but it's resolved now" (if that's true).

@Slaknation Definitely put the construction and any other work or volunteer work on the resume', it helps a lot.  Of course, you want to show that your now interested in software development.

@JosephDoggie Even if I have to tell them that I got fired?

@Slaknation that's a difficult call, it still is probably better to put it on resume'.  If you were fired for lack of construction ability, that's not necessarily a limiting factor.  If you were late/missing, etc. that makes it harder to justify.

@JosephDoggie I should also mention that I only worked at one construction job for a month before getting fired and another for a week before getting fired.

@Slaknation Probably the total of about five or six weeks at the construction jobs are not worth putting on the resume'.  If there's any way to "cover: the period of time honestly try to do that (e.g. self-study).  Employers always want to establish what's going on in various periods of time.  Also, sometimes the short-term jobs will show up in a background check, so be careful.  If you have someone from an unemployment office or mentor program that can help you, I'd do so....

You do not have to mention on your resume that you were fired.  If during the interview they ask about the construction work, you can use humor: "I learned that I do better working in a building than I do trying to make a building."

As a business owner, I would suggest getting a job with a smaller company or as a freelancer through a third party.
Given the mental health issues, starting a business is pressure that you just don't need on a whim. Focus on the dev, if that is what you enjoy doing and build from there.
Having customers, vendors, AR/AP, etc. sucks if that isn't your primary goal.
Only you can decide if pivoting away from dev makes sense for you. Longterm, find and do what you love to do. That is what it is all about.

ok thank you. Do you think I should put my jobs doing construction on my resume? Or do you think I should leave them off? If I put them on, it helps show that I wasn't doing anything, but I also would have to explain that I got fired from them. But if I leave them off, then they will wonder why I didn't work for awhile. Also, do you think I should put my experience delivering pizzas on there?

If you don't put work experience on the resume, be prepared to explain what you were doing with the time.

At least in the US, if you are having some difficulties, it's much better to get a job with a larger company than a smaller company.  If you do freelance work, probably won't get insurance, etc.

@JosephDoggie I don't care about insurance. I don't trust doctors so I don't have health insurance

@Slaknation include the other jobs. Keep the explainations on the resume short.  In software dev, sprints of other experience isn't always as negative IMHO as it is for other occupations. You might consider keeping your thoughts about doctors to yourself. Some people might be concerned about the logic of that statement.

"I don't trust doctors so I don't have health insurance" -- I definitely had an AHA! moment when I read that. If you won't talk to a doctor, you could be as mad as a hatter and never know it, in which case I don't want you anywhere near my software let alone a welding rig or a freight truck.

@Slaknation "I don't trust doctors" People I have known who say that have also a deep distrust of all authority. That made them "bad employees" no matter what industry they were in. They questioned everything. I suggest working on that issue first before trying to find a job.

@DavidR Fair enough. Everyone is entitled to their opinion. I personally don't trust them after this scamdemic. I have family members that got the  and haven't been the same since.

@Slaknation: Get the  ! Any change will be an improvement.
